# How to produce a datetime string using a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, automation

I am trying to create a string for a document automation project that connects to a pandas dataframe and takes a date and produces it in this format: %A, %B %d, %Y (Friday, April 21, 2023).

My code I have used so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# testing data
trial_data = [["EXA001.701","4/21/2023"]]
trial_df = pd.DataFrame(trial_data, columns=["matterNo","trial_date"])
...

date = trial_df.loc[trial_df['matterNo']== matter_input, 'trial_date'].iloc[0]

dt_obj = datetime.strftime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
dt_string = datetime.strptime(dt_obj, '%A, %B %d, %Y')
dt_string
```

However, it appears to have an error but from what I understood my `dt_obj` was supposed to convert the variable: `date` to a datetime object.

```
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
```

I also was able to convert it to a datetime object prior using pd.to_datetime but got an error when I tried to convert it to the %A, %B %d, %Y format.

Does anyone know how to remedy this issue? I would prefer to use pandas but would gladly hear out any other alternatives!

Comment: Seems like you've got `strftime` and `strptime` backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# testing data
trial_data = [["EXA001.701","4/21/2023"]]
trial_df = pd.DataFrame(trial_data, columns=["matterNo","trial_date"])


matter_input = "EXA001.701"
date = trial_df.loc[trial_df['matterNo']== matter_input, 'trial_date'].iloc[0]

# Convert string date to datetime object
dt_obj = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
# Convert datetime object to desired string format
dt_string = dt_obj.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y')
print(dt_string)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer:

```
from datetime import datetime
# 
# # testing data
trial_data = [["EXA001.701","4/21/2023"]]
trial_df = pd.DataFrame(trial_data, columns=["matterNo","trial_date"])
trial_df['trial_date'] = pd.to_datetime(trial_df['trial_date'])
matter_input = "EXA001.701"
date = trial_df.loc[trial_df['matterNo']== matter_input, 'trial_date'].iloc[0]

dt_obj = datetime.strftime(date, "%A %B %d %Y")
dt_string = datetime.strptime(dt_obj, '%A %B %d %Y')
print(dt_obj)

Friday April 21 2023
```